# How to setup working directory for GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, working-directory

#### Problem:

I have to copy files from *Coding folder* to *Local repository*.
And then I `push origin` from *Local repository*.

#### Solution needed:

I want *Coding folder* to behave like a *working directory*, linked to *Local repository*.
I need to be able to `push origin` from *Coding folder*.

Maybe it involves `git --bare` but I'm not yet sure how to setup a *working directory*.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial question confused me. I understand you now

Setup the local repo

```
mkdir myrepo.git
cd myrepo.git
git init --bare
```

---

If you're starting a new project

```
git clone myrepo.git
cd myrepo
echo "hello world" > readme
git add readme
git commit -m "first commit"
git push -u origin master
```

---

If you have an existing git repo but you want to push to a bare one

```
cd myexistingproject
git remote add origin /path/to/myrepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: You've created 'my-project' which is a local repository. Normally you don't code inside it. Your coding directory is different from this one. If you've to push to origin you push from local repository. I'm asking if it's possible to push from my coding folder without ever touching local repository folder. Which I think is possible.

Comment: I understand you better now. I updated my answer. おやすみなさい

Comment: Okay I now understand that '--bare' creates an offsite storage for local code repos. I've added myProject.git directory as origin to local repo. But where should I add github's ssh origin to?

Comment: I think I've figured it out. I thought it was like this: workingFolder > local git repo > remote git repo. But you cannot push to remote repo if you've a bare repo. To push code to remote repo, you'll have to init git in workingFolder itself. So you either have an offsite local bare repo, or a remote github.com repo. I think I am right... Am I?